# reversing a hash to it's string in solidity

Tags: hash, solidity

hello I am trying to save the physical address of somewhere in my contract but I found out
that large strings will cost more gas, so I am trying to save the string as a hash, and whenever I want, reverse that hash and get the string which I hashed.
Q1: is it possible?
Q2: if not, have you got any idea to save a large string with the lowest possible gas usage?

```
    bytes32 x = keccak256("some large string");
    function reverse (x) pure public returns(string memory){
    string memory reversed = "here I want to unhash the x somehow !!";
    return y;
    }
```

output = some large string

Comment: To my knowledge a hash is **supposed** to be a one-way function and recreation of the original data from the hash is not possible (unless you can map all possible in and outputs).
If you want to save large data you are likely looking at compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1

No, it's not possible, hash functions are one way, and there's also a chance that 2 different inputs may conclude the same hash output. Hashes are meant to check if the integrity of a message, for example, if a string was modified during a process, by comparing their hashes ( the original string's hash and the received string's hash ).

- 2

MOST optimal way of storing big chunks of data is by using IPFS, a blockchain focused on data storage, then, in your smart contract what you'll store is a link to an IPFS file, this is usually how NFTs work since they don't store the literal data (png if its a monkey picture, XML or JSON if its credentials or certificates ) in the smart contract because that data its too big and it costs too much gas to read.

Anyway, if you still want to keep your string in your smart contract, the most optimal way would be the use a fixed array of `bytesXX` because `string` is a dynamic array of bytes. And if you won't modify that string at all, make it `constant` so the declaration will be inlined by the compiler, and it won't use storage.

Comment: thanks for that complete explanation, and my point is to keep that safe from anything, that is why i'm trying to save it on blockchain, and i'm using that string on a mapping and because its keeping an address for each place the string's won't have the same length, and yes its not gonna change , you got any idea to use immutable variable in a mapping ?

Comment: Well, the easiest way i can come up with is by creating a function that checks if that mapping address is empty when setting its value, since constant and immutable can only be set on compile time or on the constructor, but you cant create a constant like storage variable that's set after deployment. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/Frenzoid/62b4f2c5bb7efe72934394f4235ecb5c

Comment: oh, nice idea tnx brother, for your time and example on github :)